Can't run inference SDK on AWS Lambda due to error with multiprocessing
I am running this code on AWS Lambda
import os
from inference_sdk import InferenceHTTPClient


def handler(event, context):
    client = InferenceHTTPClient(api_url="https://detect.roboflow.com",
                                 api_key=os.environ["ROBOFLOW_API_KEY"])
    img_path = "./pizza.jpg"
    return client.infer(img_path, model_id="pizza-identifier/3")


As part of a docker container that looks like this:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.11

RUN yum install -y mesa-libGL

COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY pizza.jpg ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY lambda_function.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

CMD [ "lambda_function.handler" ]

My requirements.txt contains nothing but inference==0.9.17
When the code runs I get the following error. I have been trying to fix this and tried workarounds but to no avail. I understand that the error is somehow related to multiprocessing. I found this post from which I understand that multiprocessing isn't possible on AWS Lambda, however, my script does not control or trigger any multiprocessing. I am incredibly frustrated since I've been working on this for 9 hours now and would appreciate any hints!
This is the full error:
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 38] Function not implemented",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "requestId": "703be804-fd86-4b44-88f9-ac54c87717be",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in handler\n    return client.infer(img_path, model_id=\"pizza-identifier/3\")\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/inference_sdk/http/client.py\", line 82, in decorate\n    return function(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/inference_sdk/http/client.py\", line 237, in infer\n    return self.infer_from_api_v0(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/inference_sdk/http/client.py\", line 299, in infer_from_api_v0\n    responses = execute_requests_packages(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/inference_sdk/http/utils/executors.py\", line 42, in execute_requests_packages\n    responses = make_parallel_requests(\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/inference_sdk/http/utils/executors.py\", line 58, in make_parallel_requests\n    with ThreadPool(processes=workers) as pool:\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py\", line 930, in __init__\n    Pool.__init__(self, processes, initializer, initargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py\", line 196, in __init__\n    self._change_notifier = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 113, in SimpleQueue\n    return SimpleQueue(ctx=self.get_context())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/queues.py\", line 341, in __init__\n    self._rlock = ctx.Lock()\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/context.py\", line 68, in Lock\n    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/synchronize.py\", line 169, in __init__\n    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/synchronize.py\", line 57, in __init__\n    sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(\n"
  ]
}


That library appears to be using a semaphore which is an O/S controlled entity for sharing access to data in a multi-process environment.  Based on the error it looks like Lambda doesn't support this.  I'd test to see if a Docker based image would work for what you want.

Lambda doesn't provide shared memory in the form of /dev/shm, so Python's multiprocessing.Pool and multiprocessing.Queue, or anything that depends on them, won't work.

@stdunbar I am already using a docker image
